# Laravel Query Existence of several

Tags: laravel, performance, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I read the Laravel documentation about the query builder, however I can not figure this out:

Current situation:
My User Model has many upperCategories and my upperCategory Model has many subCategories. That is why I can do this: `auth()->user()->upperCategories()->with('subCategories')->get()->toArray();`
Note that I am using eager loading for improved performance. This code is working fine. It returns something like that:

```
    [
       "id" => 1,
       "user_id" => 2,
       "category" => "Project",
       "sub_categories" => [
         [
           "id" => 1,
           "upper_category_id" => 1,
           "category" => "myFristProject",
         ],
         [
           "id" => 4,
           "upper_category_id" => 1,
           "category" => "mySecondProject",
         ],
    ]
```

What I want:
My SubCategory Model has many microCategories. I want to check for every SubCategory if a microCategory exists so at the end I can create something like:

```
       [
           "id" => 1,
           "user_id" => 2,
           "category" => "Project",
           "sub_categories" => [
             [
               "id" => 1,
               "upper_category_id" => 1,
               "category" => "myFristProject",
               "micro_category_exists" => true,
             ],
             [
               "id" => 4,
               "upper_category_id" => 1,
               "category" => "mySecondProject",
               "micro_category_exists" => false,
             ],
        ]
```

What I **do not want** is to send one sql-query for every subCategory I have. I know that I could solve the problem like this using the exists() method, however I would like to make everything in a single query. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you get if you are trying like this ```auth()->user()->loadMissing(['upperCategories.subCategories])```

Comment: @EncangCutbray Thank you for helping me. Unfortunately this does not work. I am getting the user Model containing all upperCategories, which contain all their subCategories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to add an extra field to the subCategories relationship, you'll need to add a Closure to the `with` function

```
auth()->user()
    ->upperCategories()
    ->with([
        'subCategories' => function ($query) {
            $query->withCount('microCategories as micro_category_exists');
        }
    ])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

This simple query will load the microCategories **COUNT**, giving you something like this:

```
"sub_categories" => [
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "upper_category_id" => 1,
        "category" => "myFristProject",
        "micro_category_exists" => 5,
    ],
    [
        "id" => 4,
        "upper_category_id" => 1,
        "category" => "mySecondProject",
        "micro_category_exists" => 0,
    ],
]
```

You could use those numbers as truthy/falsy values (`0` can be casted as `false` in php).

If you really want the truth values in the query, you'd need to write some custom logic. In the most recent versions of laravel, the `withAggregate` function exists which makes this really easy.

```
auth()->user()
    ->upperCategories()
    ->with([
        'subCategories' => function ($query) {
            $query->withAggregate('microCategories as micro_category_exists', 'count(*) > 0');
        }
    ])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

```
"sub_categories" => [
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "upper_category_id" => 1,
        "category" => "myFristProject",
        "micro_category_exists" => true,
    ],
    [
        "id" => 4,
        "upper_category_id" => 1,
        "category" => "mySecondProject",
        "micro_category_exists" => false,
    ],
]
```